# How to get only one component from dymamiczone strapi bookshelf

Tags: node.js, strapi, bookshelf.js

I have this dynamiczone field in the model and i need this field for some endpoints so i made this **"autoPopulate": false** now I need to fetch only one component for e.g "extra-options.file-upload" but it's not working

```
"extra_options": {
  "type": "dynamiczone",   
  "autoPopulate": false,   
  "components": [       
    "extra-options.file-upload",
    "extra-options.photo-gallery",       
    "extra-options.embed-link"
  ]
}
```

I'm using MySQL database and this is the query in which I'm trying to get the value

```
entities = await strapi.query('model').find({ id: 1 }, ['extra-options.file-upload'])
```

But it returns all the three components

Answer (score 0):

Hello I don't think it's possible to do that with the populate option.
You will fetch all compose or nothing.

I suggest using the GraphQL API to achieve this request.